# Documentation options for Nancy Rest API

Tags: rest, nancy

Have developed a REST API (Nancy) that is currently only documented in MS Word (Manually). There must be an easier why to do this. Have looked into the Nancy.Swagger class but still feels like a lot of manual work.

Are there any alternatives, and is Swagger the current production standard?